# Join Array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Could someone help me explain this?  I have two snippets of code

```
$a =array( 
       array(1,2,3), 
       array(4,5,6),
       array(7,8,9)
 );


 $b = array( 
           array(8),
           array(10),
           array(12)
    );
```

now i want to expect results as

```
 $ c = array( 
           array(1,2,3,8), 
           array(4,5,6,10),
           array(7,8,9,12)
   );
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: `array_map('array_merge',$a,$b)`